# Design advice in Android application

Tags: android, architecture, android-service, android-sensors

I'm making an application in Android that should detect, classify and map road surface anomalities (potholes, speedbumps, road rugosity/roughness, etc.) using mobile sensors (accelerometer, GPS), and I'm in need of a little advice on some design choices since I'm a quite new to Android development.

So far, I have created a background service (using AsyncTask) that reads the sensors and stores data in buffers.
I need to use the data provided by the service to perform some low level filters and computations which I must then use for the pothole/speedbump/rugosity/mapping/etc. detection procedures.

I want to somehow modularise/layer these procedures such that the lowest level filters provide the data for higher level procedures and I'd love some suggestions/best practices on how to achieve this.

I'd also like to know how to consume the data provided by the background service (timer triggered event at a given interval, ...) ?

Comment: Think of your procedures like small blackbox objects with inputs and outputs. You can then find a way to wire them together, maybe something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern - there are too many ways to approach this to give the "correct" answer

Comment: I'm not looking for the "correct" answer, but merely for suggestions to make sure I'm not starting this in a completely wrong manner. Anyways, thanks for the feedback

Comment: Stackoverflow is unfortunately meant for questions that can be answered with 1 correct answer :)

Comment: That is true, but I always look beyond the green tick for valuable feedback on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no Android expert, but I have been developing an app with similar structure than yours. To accomplish it, I am using an actual long-running [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for the top-level background proccessing and data management which launchs different [Threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) to perform low-level computing and data acquisition.

For the communication threads->service, I am registering a BroadcastReceiver in the service and broadcasting information from the threads. To communicate service->activities I am just binding the service to the activity as described in "Extending the Binder class" in Android API Guide.

So the structure is like this: 
Activity --(bound)--> Service --(spawns multiple)--> Thread

You can get communication in top-down direction by directly calling public methods in the Service and Threads and down-top by broadcasting messages and receiving them in the Activity and Service.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. I am pretty inexperienced with Android and multi threading generally and that is why I was looking for advice. I currently have a service that runs in background (via AsyncTask's doInBackground method) and collects data from the sensors, storing it into buffers which can be accessed via public methods. My idea was to make computations on the data provided by the service in some other thread, but I am not sure on how to acquire the buffers from the service (since they are updated like 80 times a second :)

Comment: Well, I am not sure about that but I think it depends on how you want to process the data. If you just need a relatively small amount of samples for the processing and you want to process the data as it arrives you might want to do it in the same thread to avoid the overhead of communicating with other threads. For a medium-sized batch of data I would try to send it as extra data in a Intent or synchronizing the Thread and calling a method to get the buffer. For large quantities of data, the best option might be saving it to a temp file and process it after the acquisition has finished.